How to pass parameters to sdf file from launch file similar to XACROS?
I am converting a model in XACROS/URDF to SDF and launching the model with launch file in roslaunch. I was able to convert the model. However to run the model I need to pass the parameters to the model similar to XACROS. Is there a way to pass parameters to the model for sdf through launch file similar to XACROS ?
P.S - I am converting models in SDF from RotorS / CrazyS package for multi-rotors. I could use Ignition but as far as I know Ignition does not have SImulink/Matlab connectivity yet.
